# Campo com formato DateTime não altera o formato para Date - Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Preciso fazer com que seja mostrado apenas o formato de data em um campo do tipo DateTime, mas estão aparecendo apenas letras no campo (mesmo que a propriedade value contendo uma data).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

VIEWMODEL:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Data em formato inválido")]
[DisplayName("Data de Emissão")]
public DateTime DataEmissao { get; set; }
```

RAZOR:

```
<input type="date" asp-for="DataEmissao" id="financeiro-parcela-data-emissao" class="form-control" />
```

HTML:

```
<input type="date" id="financeiro-parcela-data-emissao" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Data de Emissão field is required." name="DataEmissao" value="03/11/2020 00:00:00">
```

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Obrigado :)

Comment: é do próprio navegador isso ai

Comment: O Interessante @ novic é que se eu alterar type="date" para type="datetime", no razor, ele funciona corretamente, mas exibindo data + hora... eu queria apenas que fosse a data...

Comment: o `datetime` inclusive parece que está depreciado kkk se não me engano. besteira essa mudança

Answer (score 1):

Descobri, sem querer, o problema.

Estava chamando uma janela Modal a partir de outra Modal. Por algum motivo, a Controller não estava criando o prefixo da Modal que deveria ser "FinanceiroParcelaViewModel". Isso, por algum motivo, atrapalhava a exibição das datas, pois fazia como que os campos entendessem que estava null, quando na verdade, estavam "setados" com suas respectivas datas.

Solução:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("financeiro-parcela-gerenciar/editar-financeiro-parcela")]
public IActionResult EditFinanceiroParcela(FinanceiroParcelaViewModel financeiroParcelaViewModel)
{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "FinanceiroParcelaViewModel"; //Acrescentei esta linha.
    return View(_financeiroParcelaAppService.UpdateAttributes(financeiroParcelaViewModel));
}
```